# unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'method' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

```
from tkinter import *
import math
import sys

def quit():
  root.destroy()

def a_b_c():
  print_a()
  print_b()
  print_c()
  calculation()
  return

def print_a():
  get_a = a.get()
  printing_a = Label(root, text=get_a).grid(row=8, column=1)
  return

def print_b():
  get_b = b.get()
  printing_b =Label(root, text=get_b).grid(row=12, column=1)
  return

def print_c():
  get_c = c.get()
  printing_c =Label(root, text=get_c).grid(row=16, column=1)
  return


root = Tk()
a = StringVar()
b = StringVar()
c = StringVar()

root.title('Solving Quadratic Equations')

quit_b = Button(root, text="quit",command=quit).grid(row=1, column=1)
go_b = Button(root, text="go", command=a_b_c).grid(row=1, column=2)
welcome = Label(root, text="Welcome to Solving Quadratic Equations with GlaDOS",font=("Helvetica",13))
welcome.grid(row=2, column=1)


instructions = Label(root, text="So how do i use this program? is what you may ask yourself. So, for example, \n you have the equation 2x^2+5x+8=0. So the 2x^2 is a but you don't put the\n whole thing in you just but the 2 from the start in. The next thing is b\n in this case b = 5 and c is equal to 8. Once you have all you number in the boxes \n hit the go button. Remember you don't need the x's. ", font=("Helvetica",11))
instructions.grid(row=3, column=1)

line = Label(root, text="************************************************************************************************************").grid(row=4, column=1)

input_a = Label(root, text="Pls input A here", font=("Helvetica",11)).grid(row=6, column=1)
entry_a = Entry(root,textvariable=a).grid(row=7,column=1)

line = Label(root, text="************************************************************************************************************").grid(row=9, column=1)

input_b = Label(root, text="Pls input B here", font=("Helvetica",11)).grid(row=10, column=1)
entry_b = Entry(root,textvariable=b).grid(row=11,column=1)

line = Label(root, text="*************************************************************************************************************").grid(row=13, column=1)
input_c = Label(root, text="Pls input C here", font=("Helvetica",11)).grid(row=14, column=1)
entry_c = Entry(root,textvariable=c).grid(row=15,column=1)

two_a = a.get
two_b = b.get
two_c = c.get

d = two_b**2-4*two_a*two_c
def calculation():
  if d < 0:
  no_solution = Label(root, text="This equation has no real solution").grid(row=19, column=1)
  elif d == 0:
  x = (-two_b+math.sqrt(two_b**2-4*two_a*two_c))/2*two_a
  one_solution = Label(root, text="This equation has one solutions: {}".format(x)).grid(row=20, column=1)
  else:
  x1 = (-two_b+math.sqrt((two_b**2)-(4*(two_a*two_c))))/(2*two_a)
  x1 = (-two_b-math.sqrt((two_b**2)-(4*(two_a*two_c))))/(2*two_a)
  two_solution= label(root, text="This equation has two solutions: {} or {} ".format(x1,x2)).grid(row=21, colum=1)

root.mainloop()
```

why does it say unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): method or int? can someone help me to change it so it works it is for school and the teacher can't help me. I am trying to make a program that helps you to solve quadratic equations and the part at the bottom dosent work( def calculation)
thanks for helping me :)

Comment: What line does the error refer to?

Comment: The code in `calculation` is not properly indented.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning a few values:

```
two_a = a.get
two_b = b.get
two_c = c.get
```

And then doing calculations:

```
d = two_b**2-...
```

However, `a.get` is a method that retrieves the value of that `StringVar`. To actually call it and retrieve the value, you have to... well, call it, with parentheses:

```
two_a = a.get()
```

Furthermore, you will then have strings. Cast them to integers or floating-point numbers with `int` or `float`:

```
two_a = int(a.get())
# or:
two_a = float(a.get())
```

Then your arithmetic will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Please read and study this SO help page about [mcves](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
Here is an mcve based on the code you posted.  It produces the exact same error message on the last line.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.StringVar(root)
two_b = b.get
d = two_b**2
```

Raising a method to a power is nonsensical.  You need to call () the method and convert the string to a number.  Do the latter either by using DoubleVar or IntVar instead of StringVar or by passing the result of get to float() or int() before doing arithmetic on it.